# Monitoring installation and modification to windows

Tags: windows, installation

Is is possible to monitor if a user try to install software or try to do modifications to a windows system?

All installation and/or modification should be done by an administrator.  If a user try to do it by himself it should be blocked and reported by email to the administrator.

Thanks,

Comment: The installation of software can be blocked by using active domain groups.

Answer (score 0):

I use LogMeIn Pro, which can set up alerts based a large number of parameters, including software installations and settings changes.

[Feature list of LogMeIn Pro](https://secure.logmein.com/products/pro/features.aspx)
[Tutorial on Alert setup](http://help.logmein.com/selfserviceknowledgerenderer?type=FAQ&id=kA030000000DGHjCAO)

Comment: LogMeIn Pro is way to much targeted at remote access and we don't need this functionnality.  We need a tool that will report to the system administrator all attempts at executing administrative tasks.

Comment: ... executing administrative tasks BY THE USERS.